# OpenSSL .NET c# wrapper X509 certification

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, x509

Hi Iam using the OpenSSL .NET wrapper in my c# project. i want to generate an X509 certification but i don't really know the procedure. what should it contain (what parameters)...etc
this is my code, I did it after looking some tests:

```
        OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate x509 = new OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate();
        OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA rsa = new OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA();
        rsa.GenerateKeys(1024, 0x10001, null, null);
        OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey key = new OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey(rsa);
        OpenSSL.Crypto.MessageDigestContext digest = new OpenSSL.Crypto.MessageDigestContext(
                                                                 OpenSSL.Crypto.MessageDigest.SHA1);
```

I suppose that the certificate should take RSA private key and the digest as parameters and i have to configure it (date...and others parameters). 
Can any one help me about that ? to finish my code ? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following routine:

```
// Initialize the following with your information
var serial = 1234;
var issuer = new X509Name("issuer");
var subject = new X509Name("subject");

// Creates the key pair
var rsa = new RSA();
rsa.GenerateKeys(1024, 0x10001, null, null);

// Creates the certificate
var key = new CryptoKey(rsa);
var cert = new X509Certificate(serial, subject, issuer, key, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(20));

// Dumps the certificate into a .cer file
var bio = BIO.File("C:/temp/cert.cer", "w");
cert.Write(bio);
```